# C# - Converting String array to sbyte** (String[] to sbyte**)

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, clr, command-line-interface

`XFunction` is a CLI to managed C++ code (wrapper).
I want to use `XFunction(int,sbyte**)` in my C# Project and convert String array to sbyte**.

```
sbyte[][] sbytes = new sbyte[7][];
for (int argCounter = 0; argCounter < 7 ; argCounter++)
{   
     //get the byte array
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(argument[argCounter]);
    //convert it to sbyte array
    sbytes[argCounter] = new sbyte[bytes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    sbytes[argCounter][i] = (sbyte)bytes[i];
}
```

when I calling:

```
XFunction(7,sbytes);
```

and buid, generate this error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'XFunction(int, sbyte**)' has
>   some invalid arguments      Argument 2: cannot convert from 'sbyte[][]'
>   to 'sbyte**'

How can I fixed this error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved by:

```
            sbyte[][] sbytes = new sbyte[6][];
            for (int argCounter = 0; argCounter < 6 ; argCounter++)
            {   
                get the byte array
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(argument[argCounter]);
                convert it to sbyte array1
                sbytes[argCounter] = new sbyte[bytes.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                    sbytes[argCounter][i] = (sbyte)bytes[i];
            }
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (sbyte* junk = &sbytes[0][0])
                {
                    sbyte*[] arrayofptr = new sbyte*[sbytes.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < sbytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        fixed (sbyte* ptr = &sbytes[i][0])
                        {
                            arrayofptr[i] = ptr;
                        }
                    }
                    fixed (sbyte** ptrptr = &arrayofptr[0])
                    {
                        XFunction(7, ptrptr);                            
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Documentation for fixed says "After statement is executed, any pinned variables are unpinned and subject to garbage collection. Therefore, do not point to those variables outside the fixed statement." You are now collecting your pointers to your arrayofptr with separete fixed statement this means that if garbace collection hits at bad time pointers might point to invalid data in memory. That is why I choosed recursive approach. So be warned that you might run into problems with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [fixed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(v=vs.71).aspx) to get pointer to your array and to prevent garbage collection from relocating your variable.

You may want to do something like this:

```
public static unsafe void CallXFunction(int a, sbyte[][] array)
{
    var pointerArray = new sbyte*[array.Length];

    // Recursive fixing so that whole array get's pinned at same time   
    // (never use fixed pointer outside of fixed{} statement)
    Action<int> fixArray = null;   
    fixArray = (pos) =>
    {
        fixed (sbyte* ptr = array[pos])
        {
            pointerArray[pos] = ptr;

            if (pos <= (array.Length - 2))
            {
                fixArray(pos + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                fixed (sbyte** pointer = pointerArray)
                {
                    XFunction(a, pointer);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    fixArray(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
But in addition to this, it's need to for loop!